# Making a quiz app, stuck on a function

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple quiz app. But I'm stuck on ordering the functions.

Here is the code

```
// questions set
var qtnsSet = [
  // format: [question, [comma, separated, options], index of correct ans. eg. 1]

  ["What is the full form of IP?", ["Internet Provider", "Internet Port", "Internet Protocol"], 2],
  ["Who is the founder of Microsoft?", ["Bill Gates", "Steve Jobs", "Steve Wozniak"], 0],
  ["Full name of IBM?", ["Internet Business Machine", "International Business Machine", "Indian Business Machine"], 1]
]


// init vars
var qtnNo = 0,
  score = 0;

// define elements
var qtnContainer = $("qtn-container"),
  optnsContainer = $("optns-container"),
  submitBtn = $("submit-btn");

function $(id) { // Shortcut for document.getElementById
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function askQtn() { // ask question
  var optns = qtnsSet[qtnNo][1], // options array
    optnsHtml = "";
  for (var optnNo = 0; optnNo < optns.length; optnNo++) {
    optnsHtml += createOptnHtml(optnNo, optns[optnNo]);
  }
  qtnContainer.textContent = qtnsSet[qtnNo][0]; // question
  optnsContainer.innerHTML = optnsHtml; // options
}

function createOptnHtml(optnNo, optn) { // create html elements for options
  // eg. <li><input type='radio' name='optn' value='Option' id='optn-0'>
  // <label for='optn-0'>Option</label></li>
  return "<li><h3><input type='radio' name='optn' value='" + optn + "' id='optn-" + optnNo + "'>" +
    " <label for='optn-" + optnNo + "'>" + optn + "</label></h3></li>";
}

function getGivenAns() { // get the answer given by user
  var optns = document.getElementsByName("optn");
  for (var optnNo = 0; optnNo < optns.length; optnNo++) {
    if (optns[optnNo].checked) {
      return optnNo; // index of the chosen answer
    }
  }
}

function checkAns() { // check if user's right or not
  if (getGivenAns() == qtnsSet[qtnNo][2]) {
    score += 6; // 6 points for right answer
  }
}

function submitAns() {
  if (qtnNo <= qtnsSet.length) {
    if (getGivenAns()) {
      checkAns();
      qtnNo++;
      askQtn();
    } else {
      alert("Please choose an answer.");
    };
  } else {
    alert("Score: " + score);
  };
}

window.addEventListener("load", askQtn, false);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitAns, false);
```

I'm unable to configure the `submitAns()` function so that every thing works correctly.
How can I order the functions inside `submitAns()`?

Comment: @suspectus thanks for the edit. I didn't notice that typo.

Comment: no probs - it tickled me to think that one could do that to a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
getGivenAns()
```

Returns the index of the options, which can be 0 if the first option is selected which would evaluate to false here:

```
if (getGivenAns()) {
```

so just return true if an option is checked.

Also

```
if (qtnNo <= qtnsSet.length) {
```

Will be true after the last question it should just be

```
if (qtnNo < qtnsSet.length) {
```